# Length of composition series and injective homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> Let $f:M\rightarrow N$ be an injective $R$-module homomorphism. Show that $l(M)\leq l(N)$ where $l(M)$ denote the number of nonzero submodules in a composition series of $M$.

My solution:
Since $f$ is injective, we have  Ker($f$)=$\{0\}$. Define $g:M \rightarrow \frac{M}{\text{Ker}(f)}$ by $g(x)=x+{0}$. Hence,$g$ is isomorphism. Therefore, $M$ is isomorphic to $\frac{M}{\text{Ker}(f)}$. Thus, $l(M)=l(\frac{M}{\text{Ker}(f)})$. By isomorphism theorem, we have $\frac{M}{\text{Ker}(f)}$ isomophic to Im$(f) \leq N$. Thus, $l(M)=l(\text{Im}(f))\leq l(N)$.

I'm not really sure about my answer. Is there any elementary and better solution? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You have reduced to the case of $M$ being a submodule of $N$. Thus, you still have to explain why the composition length of a submodule $M\subseteq N$ is less than or equal to the composition length of $N$.

Comment: @user1: No, Since M isomorphic to Im f and Im f is submodule of N  we have $l(M)=l(im f)\leq l(N)$

Comment: That's exactly what you need to explain ($l(\operatorname{im}f)\leq l(N)$). [It might just be Theorem X.Y.Z in a textbook you are using, but you still need the explanation.]

Comment: @user1. I have explain it in my solution. Read carefully before judging!

Comment: After a second careful reading, I don't see an argument for why "the composition length of a *submodule* $M\subseteq N$ is less than or equal to the composition length of $N$."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $0=M_0\subsetneq \cdots \subsetneq M_n=M$ be a composition series for $M$. Since $f$ is an injective homomorphism, $f(M_i)$ is a submodule for each $M_i$ and strict inclusions are preserved, so $f(M_0)\subsetneq \cdots\subsetneq f(M_n)\subseteq N$, thus $l(N)\geq n=l(M)$.

Comment: With your argument could we conclude that $l(N)=l(M)$? Since every module have the same length of composition series

Comment: @beginner No, because $f(M_n)$ might not equal $N$, so the resulting series might not be a composition series.

Comment: OK, i get it. The composition series of $N$ is the refinement of the series $f(M_0)\subset ... \subset f(M_n)$, so $l(N) \geq n$.

Comment: @beginner Rather it is a continuation of $f(M_0)\subset\dots\subset f(M_n)$ to get all the way up to $N$. I.e. a refinement of the series $f(M_0)\subset\dots\subset f(M_n)\subseteq N$.